# Eloquent query : Retrieve the list of offices where the user possess all the desks, not just one (nested whereHas)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, wherehas

I want to retrieve all the `offices` ( with the `desks` eager loaded) but I only want `offices` where the `user` possess all the `desks` in the `office`

I have the following models and relationships between them :

[image: Database Modelisation]

I came up with the following query which seems to almost work :

```php
<?php 

Office::query()
    ->whereHas('desks', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('possessedDesks', function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', auth()->id);
        });
    })
    ->with(['desks'])
    ->get();
```

The current query seems to return a result where if a user own a single `desk` in the `office` then the office is returned in the query. Am I missing something ? Is there a way to be more strict in the whereHas to have some kind of `and` instead of a `or`

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Edit :

Thanks to Tim Lewis's comment I tried this with not more result :

```php
<?php

Office::query()
    ->withCount('desks')
    ->whereHas('desks', function ($query) {
        $query
            ->whereHas('possessedDesks', function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id', auth()->id);
            })
            ->has('possessedDesks', '=', 'desks_count');
    })
    ->with(['desks'])
    ->get();
```

Edit 2 :

I managed to get exactly what I need, outside of an Eloquent query. The problem is still persist since I need it to be in an Eloquent query because I need this for a query string request (Search engine).

```php
<?php

$offices = Office::query()
    ->with(['desks'])
    ->get();

$possessedDeskIds = auth()->user->with('possessedDesks.desk')->possessedDesks()->get()->pluck('desk.id');

$fullyOwnedOffices = [];
foreach($offices as $office) {
    $officeDeskIds = $office->desks()->pluck('id');

    $atLeastOneDeskIsNotPossessed = false;
    foreach($officeDeskIds as $officeDesk) {
        if ($possessedDeskIds->doesntContain($officeDesk)) {
            $atLeastOneAromaIsNotPossessed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$atLeastOneDeskIsNotPossessed) {
        $fullyOwnedOffices[] = $office;
    }
}
```

Edit 3 :

Ok, With the previous edit and the need to have some kind of one line query (for the query string of a search engine) I simplified the request since the nested `whereHas` where hard to make sense of.

It's not the prettiest way to do it, It add more query for the process, but with the code from the Edit2 I can generate an array of Ids of the `Office` where all the `Desk` are possessed by the user. With that I can just say that when this option is required in the search engine, I just select the ones my algorithm above gave me and no more logic in the query.

If some genius manage to find a way to optimize this query to add the logic back inside of it, I'll take it but for now it works as expected.

Thanks Tim for your help

```php
<?php

class SearchEngineController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $officesWithAllDesksPossessed = collect([]);
        if ($request->has('with_possessed_desks') && $request->input('with_possessed_desks')) {
            $publicOffices = Office::query()
                ->isPublic()
                ->with(['desks'])
                ->get();

            $possessedDeskIds = currentUser()
                ->possessedDesks()
                ->with('desk')
                ->get()
                ->pluck('desk.id');

            foreach($publicOffices as $office) {
                $publicOfficesDeskIds = $office->desks()->pluck('id');

                $atLeastOneDeskIsNotPossessed = false;
                foreach($publicOfficesDeskIds as $officeDesk) {
                    if ($possessedDeskIds->doesntContain($officeDesk)) {
                        $atLeastOneDeskIsNotPossessed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!$atLeastOneDeskIsNotPossessed) {
                    $officesWithAllDesksPossessed->push($office);
                }
            }

            $officesWithAllDesksPossessed = $officesWithAllDesksPossessed->pluck('id');
        }


        return Inertia::render('Discover', [
            'offices'=> OfficeResource::collection(
                Office::query()
                    ->isPublic()
                    ->with(['desks'])
                    ->when($request->input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
                        $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                    })
                    ->when($request->input('with_possessed_desks'), function ($query, $active) use($officesWithAllDesksPossessed) {
                        if ($active === 'true') {
                            $query->whereIn('id', $officesWithAllDesksPossessed);
                        }
                    })
                    ->paginate(10)
                    ->withQueryString()
            ),
            'filters' => $request->only(['search', 'with_possessed_desks']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"where if a user own a single desk"* - Indeed; that is how `whereHas()` works  If you want to enforce _all_ of them, a separate `has('desks', /* count of all desks in office */)` can be added, so your query will only return if both the `whereHas()` and `has()` clauses pass. I'm not too sure of the syntax you'd use here to calculate that count; see if you can adapt your code to that 

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be exactly what I need but I am also a little bit foggy on how to achieve this! I tried with a `->withCount('desks')` and `->has('desks.possessedDesks', '>=', 'desks_count')` but it doesn't seems to change anything with the query. I'm really not sure if this is a the right place. ( I edited the posts to reflect how I tried it)

Comment: Yeah, it's usually a lot simpler, but since you have nested `whereHas()`, I'm not sure how it behaves... You _could_ do a separate query to get the count, then use that in `has('desks', $totalDesksCount)`. Alternatively, if you can post the migrations and Models/Relationships for your 4 tables, I can attempt to recreate and debug this too (tomorrow though). Thanks for editing the question and not posting your code in the comments; that's a breath of fresh air here on Stackoverflow 

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help! I'll continue also tomorrow to debug this ;) And no problem for the edit, it wouldn't have been readable in the comments... Here's a gist with the code you'd need to help me. https://gist.github.com/dib258/f12528b733cb0124edb70cb18e53816c

Comment: Alrighty... So update on this, I wasn't able to get this working in a single Query. The counts are not scoped properly; like `$user->desks->count()` will return a count of _all_ desks, not a count of all desks in each office (since `office_id` is not on `possessed_desks`, and it wouldn't make sense there). I tried with new relationships, like `Office::withCount('desks_count')->has('userPossessedDesks', '=', 'desks_count')`, but that compares against the string `'desks_count'`, not the column alias from `withCount()`. And even then, it can't scope it on a per-office basis...

Comment: Also, as a note, the `PossessedDesk` Model is actually not needed; it can act as a Pivot between `User` and `Desk`, with a relationship on `User.php`: `public function desks() { return $this->belongsToMany(Desk::class, 'possessed_desks'); }`. It doesn't help or change anything with the code I attempted, but general practice is to _not_ define a Model for what is essentially a pivot table. Thanks again for the Gist; it was very helpful in attempting to debug this, but yeah; I think the approach you have is gonna have to work, unless someone smarter than me has any other solution 

Comment: Okay, I'll keep what I came up with for now until the choosen one comes along. ^^' And I also realised that `PossessedDesk` should be a Pivot table, I'll try to change this later in my database when I have time. Thank you for the help! ;)